# ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender not closing after firing server side event

Tags: asp.net, ajax, popup

Hi I am using ModalPopupExtender and confirmbuttonextender to throw a confirmation popup to the user. If the user click 'Yes' then I have some lines of code to execute. The problem i am facing is, after the user clicks 'Yes' the server side code gets executed correctly, but the modal popup window would not close. Can anyone help me out here please?

Comment: i have tried .Hide(), but it is not working

Comment: You have to provide some code, try to debug on your own and share results here.